# Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to 200.0.1.102:55555. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)

Tags: configuration

I don't know myself need to wait.I have set the torrc.conf correctly.And I have seen the circuit is built by nyx. please help me
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just a general note: i would advise you to post text instead of screenshots (additional screenshots are ok, but most of the time not nessesary). - no one hast to fiddle around with tiny fonts and bad colors and it is by far more likely others with similar problems or solutions will find your post via websearch.

Comment: Stupid question, but what exactly are you trying to do? You didn't say what you are doing or what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: sorry and thank you very much!  I have resolved this question,this is my first time to use this forum, next time  I will provide more clear description.